# Python: Assertion error when converting a string to binary

Tags: python, binary, ascii, assert

I am getting AssertionError when testing some basic functions in my python program. This is the scenario:

I have written a function that converts a single letter into binary from ASCII:

```
def ascii8Bin(letter):
    conv = ord(letter)
    return '{0:08b}'.format(conv)
```

Next there's a function that uses the previous function to convert all the letters in a word/sentence into binary:

```
def transferBin(string):
    l = list(string)
    for c in l:
        print ascii8Bin(c)
```

Now when I try to assert this function like this:

```
def test():
    assert transferBin('w') == '01110111'
    print "You test yielded no errors"

print test()
```

It throws an AssertionError. Now I looked up the binary alphabet and tripple checked: w in binary is definitely 01110111. I tried calling just the transferBin('w') and it yielded 01110111 like it should.

I am genuinely interested in why the assertion fails. Any insight is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't *return* anything. You use `print`, which writes text to `stdout`, but you are not testing for that.

As such, `transferBin()` returns `None`, the default return value for functions without an explicit `return` statement.

You'll have to collect the results of each `ascii8Bin()` result into a list and join the results into a string:

```
def transferBin(string):
    results = [ascii8Bin(c) for c in l]
    return '\n'.join(results)
```

This'll use newlines to separate the result for each character; for your single character `'w'` string that'll give you the expected string.

Note that you don't need to turn `l` in to a list; you can iterate over strings directly; you'll get individual characters either way.

Comment: It could also be a generator, with `for c in string: yield ascii8Bin(c)`

Comment: @Reticality: but then the test, as written, wouldn't work, you'd have to use `next(transferBin('w'))`. When still at the level of knowing the difference between `print` and `return`, I am hesitant to introduce generators.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return, you are comparing to `None` not the string. python will return None from a function if you don't specify a return value.

```
def transferBin(s):
    l = list(s)
    for c in l:
       return ascii8Bin(c) # return
```

You are basically doing `assert None == '01110111'`, also if you are only going to have  single character string simply `return ascii8Bin(string)`, having a loop with a `return` like in your code will return after the first iteration so the loop is redundant.

If you actually have multiple characters just use join and just iterate over the string you don't need to call list on it to iterate over a string:

```
def transferBin(s):
    return "".join(ascii8Bin(ch) for ch in s)
```

You can also just do it all in your transferBin function:

```
def transferBin(s):
    return "".join('{0:08b}'.format(ord(ch)) for ch in s)
```